# Mercurial - diff command with specific string

Tags: mercurial

When comparing two revisions, I would like to output only the lines containing a specific string:

```
hg diff -r 1:4 "world"
```

How can I achieve this ?

For example, searching the following file:

File @ rev 1:

```
Hello
```

File @ rev 2:

```
Hello world
```

File @ rev 3:

```
Hello you
```

File @ rev 4

```
Hello me
```

The output would be

```
-r2 + Hello world
-r3 - Hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

Without revision-ranges it will be [hg grep](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/grep) (with slightly different output by default)

> To get it to print every revision that contains a change in match
>   status ("-" for a match that becomes a non-match, or "+" for a
>   non-match that becomes a match), use the `--diff` flag